# Understanding the symbol "<-" when using State Monad?

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

In [Haskell/Understanding monads/State](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads/State) there is a snippet code:

```
type GeneratorState = State StdGen
rollDie :: GeneratorState Int
rollDie = do generator <- get
         let (value, newGenerator) = randomR (1,6) generator
         put newGenerator
         return value
```

About the Symbol `<-` in the above third line, there is an explanation:

we take out the pseudo-random generator with `<-` in conjunction with get. get overwrites the monadic value (The `a` in `m a`) with the state, binding the generator to the state. (If in doubt, recall the definition of get and `>>=` above).

I do not understand: (1) `generator` is corresponding to the first type parameter of the definition `State`? (2)  why `generator` is just one of the two parameters of `State`, not two? Of course, from the context, the answer is obvious, but I do not know the concrete rules about `<-`.

To my knowledge, when evaluating `evalState rollDie (mkStdGen 600)`, `get` will be replaced by `State (mkStdGen 0) (mkStdGen 0)` , and, according to RWH's description "`<-` pulls things out of monads", things here are not `(mkStdGen 0) (mkStdGen 0)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure about the phrasing of your question, so correct me if I misunderstood.

There is an equivalence between the syntactic sugar for the do-notation syntax `<-` and the overloaded bind operator `(>>=)`.

```
do { a <- f ; m } ≡ f >>= \a -> do { m }
```

So if you were to desugar the binds, it would look like:

```
rollDie' :: GeneratorState Int
rollDie' =
  get >>= \generator ->
    let (value, newGenerator) = randomR (1,6) generator in
    put newGenerator >>= \_ ->
      return value
```

If you understand how the State monad works, in the implementation it threads around the state in an implicit argument for each bind (i.e. `>>=`). A simplified implementation might look like:

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a,s) }

instance Monad (State s) where
  return a = State $ \s -> (a, s)

  State act >>= k = State $ \s ->
    let (a, s') = act s
    in runState (k a) s'

get :: State s s
get = State $ \s -> (s, s)

put :: s -> State s ()
put s = State $ \_ -> ((), s)
```

So the bind operator when specialized to this specific State monad has the type:

```
(>>=) :: State s a -> (a -> State s b) -> State s b
```

The function  `get` is simply the function that returns the state as an argument so you can inspect it, so it has to match the `s` type of the monad it lives in.

```
--           +--- State
--           | +- Return value (inner state)
--           | |
get :: State s s
```

Comment: Thank you! I am sorry that I almost forgot the equivalent relation between do-notation and `>>=` `RWH` described, and did not fully understand `State act` as a whole thing!